# Google Visualization Query data to table using python

Tags: python, google-fusion-tables

I have a Google Visualization Query output datatable file from here - http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=SELECT%20lat%2Clong%2CPKS%2Ctonperhour%2CGrp%2CStatus%2CPhotoPath%2CWCinfo%2Cx%2Cy%2CRSPO%2CRSPO_URL%2Ccat_plant%20FROM%201c_CnYlN8gYEtxA2N2Eay_TRiiZTFIpcONSS9NcBB&tqx=reqId%3A2

I am trying to get the data to be formatted into a table using python but not exactly sure how to go about it. The output I am looking for is something like this.

[image]

Is this something that can be done easily with python?

Comment: Sure, the FusionTables API can be used to get data from a FusionTable, and you can use whatever language tools you want to manipulate the downloaded data to make whatever you want with it. Are you having a specific issue? If not, this is a really broad question IMO

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch for your reply. The data is in a format which I am unable to quickly convert into the table I require. Does the FusionTables API allow me to get it this data in an easier format for me to manipulate the data? preferably in either python or even R. If so, how do I use the API to do that.

Comment: Fundamental details of the API are best explained and explored using the API documentation. Such details include how to use it and the format of the responses. https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/query/sqlGet https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/fusiontables/v2

Comment: Ok thanks @tehhnowch